# Ansible - Using an encrypted string as variable

Tags: svn, ansible

I'm trying to use an encrypted password for the credential of SVN.
Unfortunately I get an error.
My task:

```
- name: Export subversion directory to folder
  vars: 
    svn_pass: !vault |
            $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
            61366435663930323762326534376237329939319321939999373334616364343865333830333435
            6338646239363735376431633863333632363135383963390a636664353535663366336263626264
            39616366333132316531653461646365393332386365366264613931383165366235343238336463
            3438336335613838380a393037613636396564326465396132613162326335313932626135666333
            3630
  subversion:
    repo: svn://myserver/trunk
    dest: /tmp/svn
    username: svnuser
    password: {{ svn_pass }}
  become: true
```

The error I get:

> The offending line appears to be:
>
> ```
> username: ****
>
> password: {{ svn_pass }}
>
>            ^ here
> ```
>
> We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
>
> missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
>
> start a value. For instance:
>
> ```
> with_items:
>
>   - {{ foo }}
> ```
>
> Should be written as:
>
> ```
> with_items:
>
>   - "{{ foo }}"
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you forgot the quotes

```
password: "{{ svn_pass }}"
```